# Normal element is sum of four commuting positive elements

Tags: operator-algebras

I am stuck with the following problem :
Every normal element in a $C^*$ algebra can be written as a linear combination of four commuting positive elements.

I had tried along the following lines. Decompose the normal element $a$ as $a=x+iy$. We know that x and y commute. As both x and y are self-adjoint, let us decompose them further as $x=x_{+} - x_{-}$ and $y=y_{+}-y_{-}$ where the subscripts + and - are (loosely speaking) the unique positive and negative parts of x and y. Hence I have four positive elements now whose linear combination is $a$. I also have $x_{+}x_{-}=x_{-}x_{+}$ and $y_{+}y_{-}=y_{-}y_{+}$. But I cannot show the other commuting relations.

So my question is, am I progressing with the correct decomposition of $a$? If yes, how to show the other commuting relations?

Answer (score 1):

If you think about your argument,  you haven't used that  $a $ is normal. That will give you  $xy=yx $.

From $xy=yx$, you get $x^ny=yx^n$, and so $p(x)y=yp(x)$ for any polynomial $p$, and from here $f(x)y=yf(x)$ for any continuous function $f$.

Comment: Can you please help me out a little more? Do you imply that xy=yx will imply $x_{+}y_{+}=y_{+}x_{+}$ etc.? I am not exactly sure how to prove a relation like this.

Comment: Please see the edit.